# Angular4 HttpHeaders set incorrectly

Tags: angular, post, http-headers, httpclient

I'm trying to set a POST request unsing Angular(4.4.6) *HttpClient*. However altering the request's header is not acting properly.

Here is the code:

```
const url = "http://...";
const body = { ... };

this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), {
    params: new HttpParams().set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"),
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')  <--
}).subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the 'Content-Type' property is not set, alltough the key was stored in *Access-Control-Request-Headers*.

Expected is a behavior like HttpParams (as you can see, those were set correctly)

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are those the details of the actual POST request or from an on-flight OPTIONS request?

Comment: seems like OPTIONS request (never heared about it)

Comment: I updated the result img

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Hey Toledo, it was the OPTIONS request, the server does not support it (yet). Thx for your hint!

Answer (score -1):

try below

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.httpClient.post(
      `url`, data, { headers: headers}
    )
```

Comment: why do you think that this will make any difference?

Comment: I did, but it took no effect